# Show a Static image if browser not supporting 3D image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

In my html page want to insert a 3d image if canvas is supported by the browser and a static image if it is not. The image should be inserted on page load dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello Modernizr</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="modernizr.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (Modernizr.canvas) 
        {
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("p").show();
            });
            alert("This browser supports HTML5 canvas!");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("p").hide();
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>eseardsa
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is a 3D image, and why wouldn't the browser support it ?

Comment: HtML 5 support 3d explorer,an image that we can see by rotating all sides..

Comment: One thought is putting a default background image on the container, and if the 3d image doesn't load the user will see the default regardless.

Comment: can we add a sample code ,i tried a lot on this but still not getting the result if you can provide a sample code it will be great full,thanks you

Comment: i got it at last friends thank you all

Comment: Please don't leave unanswered questions in Stackoverflow. If my answer is not correct you can write up your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the image in your else statement similar to the code below. Although you probably want to manipulate a div instead of a p.

```
} else {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').text('<img src="yourImg.png" />');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the java script

to display image in all browser

```
<div class="cont_machines_3d">
    <div class="cont_3d">

    <iframe  height="600" scrolling="auto" src="3d/3dimage.html" width="800">
    </iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
```

to display image in ie

```
<div class="cont_machines_3d_ie"><img src="/3d/images/img.jpg" width="800" /></div>
</div>
```